# Error when running Google Map API on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am using Google Map API V2 API for the map. I have imported google-play-service libs as separated project and set it as reference of my current project.

**GoogleMap Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlemap.GoogleMap"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="This should be correct" />

</application>
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".GoogleMap" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

However, I am getting error as the logCat:

```
07-26 09:46:30.191: D/AndroidRuntime(2504): Shutting down VM
07-26 09:46:30.191: W/dalvikvm(2504): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c331f8)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemap/com.example.googlemap.GoogleMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:272)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at com.example.googlemap.GoogleMap.onCreate(GoogleMap.java:12)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     ... 11 more
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:549)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4235)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
07-26 09:46:30.199: E/AndroidRuntime(2504):     ... 21 more
07-26 09:46:38.152: I/Process(2504): Sending signal. PID: 2504 SIG: 9
```

**GoogleMap.java**

```
package com.example.googlemap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

public class GoogleMap extends Activity {

```
// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
}
```

It also tells me `MapFragment cannot be resolved to a type` error message.

Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please show the code where you instantiate your MapFragment, on your Activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SupportMapFragment` when calling your map `Fragment` instead, that is the name of the class that you have declared on your layout, like this:

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Do not forget to import the `SupportMapFragment` class.

Edit:use `SupportFragmentManager` also, that is the support version of `FragmentManager`.

Edit2: You must make your Activity extend `FragmentActivity`, so you can use getSupportFragmentManager.

Comment: It gives me two error messages after I changed the line: Type mismatch: cannot convert from com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap to com.example.googlemap.GoogleMap & Cannot cast from Fragment to SupportMapFragment

Comment: Change the name of your Activity from GoogleMap to GoogleMapActivity. You may have conflicts with the import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap class. And change the name of your Activity in the Manifest file, too.

Comment: After I changed to private com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap googleMap; and your code above, there is still an error message: The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type GoogleMap

Comment: Okay sure, it works! Thanks a lot. But there is another error message which is Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from gps.a. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You could have your Google Play Services lib deprecated. Try to update it and check if your ApiKey is really correct.

Comment: So basically this problem is related to the API key for android application?

Comment: I cannot guarantee you that it is due to that. But you must check it. And make sure you have the latest Google Play Services version on your device/emulator. And try to search for similar errors here on SO.